# Loop through results from Firebase & FirebaseIndex

Tags: firebase, angularfire

How can I read a (Firebase & FirebaseIndex) object?

My Ctrl looks like:

```
var url = 'https://MYFIREBASE.firebaseio.com/';
var toDoRef = new Firebase(url);
var index = 'podio_covers/'+ $routeParams.label_id +'/limesurveys/';
var master = 'podio_surveys';

var surveys = new FirebaseIndex(toDoRef.child(index), toDoRef.child(master))
$scope.surveys = angularFireCollection(surveys);
```

console.log ($scope.surveys) looks like:

```
[add: function, remove: function, update: function]
0: angularFireItem
    $id: "855243"
    $index: 0
    $ref: J
    current_revision: Object
    fields: Object
    initial_revision: Object
    item_id: 51176724
    last_event_on: "2013-06-09 18:56:25"
    limesurvey_data: Object
    ratings: Object
    rights: Array[10]
    title: "855243"
    __proto__: angularFireItem
add: function (item, cb) {
length: 1
remove: function (itemOrId) {
update: function (itemOrId) {
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Now - I have to loop through all the results. **$scope.surveys.length => does not work**.

Reading $scope.surveys.0.title => **Error**! I see - [add: function, remove: function, update: function] - is there a way to read $scope.surveys.0.title ?

---

**Edit 1:**  @Kato (hope to make it more clear)

Here you can see my current Ctrl attemp:

```
var url = 'https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/';
var toDoRef = new Firebase(url);
    var index = 'podio_covers/'+ $routeParams.label_id +'/limesurveys/';
    var master = 'podio_surveys';

    var surveys = new FirebaseIndex(toDoRef.child(index), toDoRef.child(master))
    $scope.surveys = angularFireCollection(surveys);
    console.log ('surveys[0]');         
    console.log ($scope.surveys[0]); **=> Undefined**

    console.log ('childRefs');          
    console.log (surveys.childRefs);


    var count = $scope.surveys.length; 
    console.log (count); **=> Undefined**


//--------------------------------------------------------------
// LOOP trough all surveys.
//--------------------------------------------------------------


for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        console.log ($scope.surveys[i]);

            // do something with $scope.surveys[i]

}
```

---

**Edit 2:**

```
    $timeout(function() {
            // Waiting until Data is loaded.

        count = $scope.surveys.length;
            console.log (count);

            //Do Loop here

    }, 1500;
```

Comment: Great! A lot clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

This will work :

```
$scope.surveys = $firebase(new Firebase(yourFBUrl));

$scope.surveys.$on("loaded", function() {
   var keys = $scope.surveys.$getIndex();
   console.log("count: " + keys.length); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>It's a little unclear what the error is; it might help to include the code that is trying to read the surveys. Are you doing that in JavaScript or with an ng-repeat directive?</del>

Best I can tell from your question, you just need to change `$scope.surveys.0` to `$scope.surveys[0]` to get into the first element. Of course, you need to wait until that data is fetched from Firebase before it will be accessible.

But really, what you probably want is something more like this in your HTML:

```
<ul ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <li ng-repeat="survey in surveys">{{survey.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your additions to the question, I can see that you are accessing the data before it has completely loaded. This data is being loaded asynchronously, so the JavaScript immediately after the angularFireCollection() will be run before the results arrive.

When you use Angular functions like ng-repeat, it watches the values for changes and waits until data loads before rendering; you want to do the same thing here.

```
var surveys = new FirebaseIndex(toDoRef.child(index), toDoRef.child(master))
$scope.surveys = angularFireCollection(surveys);

// this will be zero! data hasn't come back yet
console.log($scope.surveys.length);

// wait for changes
$scope.$watch('surveys', function() {
   console.log( $scope.surveys.length ); // greater than zero
   console.log( 'first entry', $scope.surveys[0] ); // no longer undefined
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry for my 'unclear question' => check my Edit 1. I have to loop trough all the results in my javascript Ctrl. $scope.surveys[0] / $scope.surveys[0].length reamains => Undefined. This is what I called "Error".  I really hope to find solution for this problem...  stuck for the moment.

Comment: Another idea: Is it possible to reuse my surveys as a new 'master' so I can create a new Index. Then it would be easy to add stuff through this nested FirebaseIndex?

Comment: Edit 2:  _...data is being loaded asynchronously..._ => **that was the point** - still new for me. Anyway your $scope.$watch (...) **did not work** - it passes with 'undefined' variables. I had luck with $timeout (check edit 2). This code is 'ugly as hell' - so I want a nicer way, without this timeout. **any ideas?**      Want to say THANKS for your help & your FirebaseIndex - love it!